# How to deal with: No results were returned by the query in Spring data-jpa?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I'm facing an error with the Spring data jpa in springboot. I have tried many times and looked on google, but I didn't find any solution to my problem. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

*Source Code*

****TodoController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    private TodoService todoservice ;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/AllTodos/{username}")
    public List<Todo> GetAllTodos(@PathVariable String username){
        return todoservice.getAllCount(username) ;
        
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("AllTodos/{username}/todos/{id}")
    public Todo deleteTodos(@PathVariable String username,@PathVariable Long id){
        
      
       
      return  todoservice.deleteTodos(username,id);
      
    }
```

**TodoService.java**

```
@Service
public class TodoService {
    
    
    @Autowired
   private TodoRepo todorepo ;
    
    
    public List<Todo> getAllCount(String username) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return todorepo.findAllByUsername(username);
    }


    public Todo deleteTodos(String username, Long id) {
        
         return todorepo.deleteByUsernameId(username,id);
    }
    
    
}
```

**TodoRepo.java**

```
@Repository
public interface TodoRepo extends JpaRepository<Todo,String> {

    

    List<Todo> findAllByUsername(String username);

    
    @Query(value="DELETE  FROM public.Todo WHERE username=? And id=? ",nativeQuery = true)
    Todo deleteByUsernameId(String username, Long id);

    
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:120) ~[postgresql-42.3.4.jar:42.3.4]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
```

Comment: Did you have data in your DB. IF yes then for which method in Repository you are facing this issue.

Comment: yes i am facing issue with 
   ` @Query(value="DELETE  FROM public.Todo WHERE username=? And id=? ",nativeQuery = true)
    Todo deleteByUsernameId(String username, Long id);`

Comment: DML queries does not return object either it should be INT/BOOLEAN

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are attempting to return Todo and your query does not return any results. Change the return type to void. Also why do you need a username if you have the id? Is the id not the pk? Note that you can use derived JPA delete methods, for example:

```
Long deleteByUsername(String username);
```

Note that derived delete methods either return void or the delete count as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/.

Comment: I Changed the return type to void and added two annotations in repository method as below  @Transactional,@Modifying then it working fine.

Comment: please vote my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding numbers after the ? marks and remove the word public as i illustrate below:

```
@Query(value="DELETE  FROM todo WHERE username=?1 And id=?2 ",nativeQuery = true)
Todo deleteByUsernameId(String username, Long id);
```

Comment: not working showing same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).